# git blame with commit details in emacs

Tags: git, emacs, magit

From emacs, how can I see the details (e.g. commit message) of the commit that last changed the line at point?

I have magit installed.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It is not necessary to use magit for this particular operation - vanilla emacs can do it.

(Also, because this uses vc, this should work identically in any version control system that vc supports.)

First, use the `vc-annotate` command, which is bound to the key sequence <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd>.

Now, the point should be at the commit id that you are interested in. (If not, you might need to use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> and/or <kbd>v</kbd> so that you can see which line is which, in order to navigate to the right one.) You might be able to see the diff for that file using <kbd>=</kbd> now - if you get an error beginning with "cannot diff from any revision prior...", that probably means that this revision created the file (and that's probably a bug in emacs).

The author and date are already visible in the *Annotate* buffer that `vc-annotate` produced.

To see the commit message, press <kbd>l</kbd> (the letter, not the number 1) in the *Annotate* buffer. To see what the file looked like at that revision, press <kbd>f</kbd> in either the *Annotate* buffer or the *vc-change-log* buffer.

Comment: `a` is the money action -- show blame before that change.  Saves me so much time.

Comment: I absolutely love this mode! I don't need to keep switching between the terminal and emacs. +100 if I could!

Comment: Also, output of `vc-annotate` makes more sense to me than `magit-blame-mode`.

Comment: While the output format of `vc-annotate` is in many ways better than that of `magit-blame` the latter is _much_ faster, which swings it for me.

Answer (score 47):

I'd suggest the use of `magit-blame-mode` (<kbd>M-x magit-blame-mode</kbd>). It provides the information in much nicer manner compared to `vc-annotate` and is part of the standard magit distribution. You'd probably want to bind it to some keyboard combination to toggle it quickly.

In `magit-blame-mode` use <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd> to navigate between the previous and the next change and <kbd>RET</kbd> to see the diff for a particular commit.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that. I find the `vc-annotate` output (or any traditional blame output) *much* more readable than this, personally; but it's always good to have alternatives.

Comment: I feel that the committer names waste far too much real estate in the output of `vc-annotate`.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov press `v` to hide the details, you still have the age color coded blame.

Comment: I find the output of `magit-blame-mode` pretty much unreadable in the way it mixes/interleaves code and commit history. Is there a way to get it to show output like `vc-annotate` (or `git blame`, or indeed any other readable format where the code is separate from the annotation)?

Comment: Actually, `magit-blame-mode` doesn't have the main useful feature of `vc-annotate`, its 'A' (annotate at the revision previous to the current line). So that's another reason to prefer `vc-annotate` at this point, as awesome as magit is otherwise.

Comment: How do you change the colors

Comment: @ShreevatsaR use `t` to toggle the headings in magit. See https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Blaming.html

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Actually, it looks like `M-x magit-blame` will then blame the revision before the one for that line.  So it does have the 'A' functionality.  Or you can just do `b` once you are in `magit-blame-mode`.